# Is it possible to change the foreground and background colour at the same time with terminfo?

Tags: terminfo

I'm writing a console program that needs to output styled text. Right now I'm using fixed ANSI escape codes for foreground and background colours, bold, and underline. For example, I can write `\033[35m` to change the foreground colour to purple.

The benefit of writing the codes myself is that I can chain them. I can change the background colour *and* the foreground colour with one command, which saves precious bytes:

`\033[48;5;200;38;5;100m`

I'd like to switch to using the terminfo library to make my program work on other types of terminals. However, I can't find a way to update multiple colours at once - I want to set bold and underline *and* the colours with only one `\033` and only one `m`.

There are the following commands listed in the standard, but not only do none of these seem to do what I want, I can't actually find what the first and second sets of video attributes actually are:

- **set_a_attributes:** Define second set of video attributes #1-#6
- **set_a_background:** Set background colour to #1 using ANSI escape
- **set_a_foreground:** Set foreground colour to #1 using ANSI escape
- **set_attributes:** Define first set of video attributes #1-#9

Is there a way to get what I want using only `terminfo` commands? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - terminfo does not do this:

- It lists capabilities which are likely to be provided on many different terminals
- The standard capabilities were defined ... a while back.  Same for termcap, of course.
- Color and other attributes are (with the most common terminals now) something that you might assume could be combined arbitrarily, but that is fairly recent — nothing guaranteed
- So the capabilities are in small pieces (update the foreground color, update the background color).
- The one exception is `sgr`, which can set up to 9 video attributes at a time.  None of those are color.

If you happen to be using ncurses, you *could* define your own capabilities, using [`tic -x`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tic.1m.html), and use your own interpretation for those (see for example *[ncurses user-definable capabilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_N_C_U_R_S_E_S__U_S_E_R-_D_E_F_I_N_A_B_L_E__C_A_P_A_B_I_L_I_T_I_E_S)* in the terminal database).  As long as their syntax matches the other terminfo strings, you could then use [`tparm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) to fill in the numbers (a little better than `printf`).

Comment: Bah, that's annoying! Makes sense, though.